# C# Post JSON with Authentication Header

Tags: c#, json, post

I have problem with post JSON with authentication/Authorization.. Below is my code.. opponent said that they didnt receive the header...and i have no idea why...

```
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(stringData);

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverURL);
req.Method         = "POST";
req.ContentType    = "application/json";
req.ContentLength  = data.Length;
req.Headers.Add("Authentication", merchantID);
req.Headers["Authentication"] = merchantID;

Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
newStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
string returnString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**i am writing some example code to attach header while you calling service...
hope it is needful...**

ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(stringData);

```
     HttpWebRequest reqest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUri);  
      reqest.Headers.Add(LoginName,LoginName);
      reqest.Headers.Add(AuthenticationKey,AuthenticationKey);
      reqest.Headers.Add(SessionKey,SessionKey);
      reqest.ContentType = "application/json";

   Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
   newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   newStream.Close();

  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
  string returnString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

Comment: `Add(LoginName,LoginName)`, `Add(AuthenticationKey,AuthenticationKey)` etc looks wrong. Missed enum name?

Comment: EnumCollection.ServiceRequestHeader.AuthenticationKey.ToString(),

Answer (score 0):

I cannot surely say where the problem is. It can be even on a server-side.
Recently I worked on a project with header authentication and I have noticed an interesting thing. My PHP server received these headers with 'HTTP_' prefix.

In other words, I was making a request like:

```
req.Headers.Add("Authentication", merchantID);
```

And received it on server this way:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_Authentication'];
```

I have spent a bunch of time to find it out.
You, actually, can ask your opponent if any similar header is present or ask him to examine your requests better and give you a feedback.

**Also**, try using `WebClient`. Maybe, it will help.
Furthermore, it is much more convenient.

```
string data = "{\"a\": \"b\"}";

WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("Authentication", merchantID);

var result = client.UploadString(serverURL, "POST", data);
```